# kendo - How to use add method on offline datasource in

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, offline

Is there an example using kendo offline other than a data-bound grid. Specifically, I would like to call the add method to add data to the dataset.

For example, where $scope.dsPatients is a kendo datasource, I would like to

$scope.dsPatients.add($scope.patient);

I currently get a message that the add method is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work in dojo:

http://dojo.telerik.com/@jcbowyer/OviXI